# Why are open sets of Euclidean space obviously manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I've been reading GTM$202$: *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* these days, and in Chapter $1$, the author declared that open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are manifolds for obvious reasons.

The book only defines a manifold as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is locally Euclidean (which means you can always find a neighborhood isomorphic to a ball in Euclidean space for any given $x$ in this set). I don't think this proposition is obvious for me. Is there an intuitive way to convince people that this proposition is true? Or it is just another example of "Mathematical Obvious"?

Thanks for your answer in advance！

Comment: Why do you think it is not obvious? Which part of the definition you have trouble verifying? Lastly, do you know how to define open subsets of ${\mathbb R}^n$ with respect to the standard topology?

Comment: Well, find exact neighborhood of $x$ is not quite easy for me. I just started to learn Topology, and the definition of open set still based on metric space for me, though I know Topology space is based on four axioms.

Comment: I am not asking about exact neighborhood, just the definition. It seems you do not know it and that is the source of your problem. I suggest you first read the appendix on metric spaces.

Comment: Open sets in a metric space are *defined* by the fact that every $x$ has an open ball as a neighborhood, and that's obviously homeomorphic to a ball.

Comment: Opps...I forgot that, thanks.